# How do I disable/toggle gestures in C4ios?

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, c4

Reading through the documentation [here](http://www.c4ios.com/tutorials/interactionPanning.php).

I know how to successfully setup `PAN` gestures for a `C4Object`. How would I disable a `PAN` gesture though?

Using...

```
[object setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]
```

... disables all gestures including `TAP` events and...

```
object.gestureRecognizers = NO
```

... doesn't allow me to reinitialize `PAN` gestures.

If anyone could share with me how disable `PAN` gestures (toggle `PAN` on/off) without effecting other gesture events it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to the gestures that you add to an object by using the `gestureForName:` method, which returns a `UIGestureRecognizer` object. From there, you can interact with that gesture recognizer and change its properties directly.

To toggle on/off a gesture recognizer, all you have to do is change the value of its `enabled` property.

The following works for me:

```
#import "C4WorkSpace.h"

@implementation C4WorkSpace {
    UIGestureRecognizer *gesture;
    C4Shape *square, *circle;
}

-(void)setup {
    square = [C4Shape rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    square.center = self.canvas.center;

    circle = [C4Shape ellipse:square.frame];
    circle.center = CGPointMake(square.center.x, square.center.y + 200);
    [self listenFor:@"touchesBegan" fromObject:circle andRunMethod:@"toggle"];

    [self.canvas addObjects:@[square, circle]];

    [square addGesture:PAN name:@"thePan" action:@"move:"];
    gesture = [square gestureForName:@"thePan"];
}

-(void)toggle {
    gesture.enabled = !gesture.isEnabled;
    if(gesture.enabled == YES) square.fillColor = C4GREY;
    else square.fillColor = C4RED;
}

@end
```

The **key** part of this example is the following:

```
    [square addGesture:PAN name:@"thePan" action:@"move:"];
    gesture = [square gestureForName:@"thePan"];
```

Notice, in the implementation there is a `UIGestureRecognizer` variable called `gesture`. What we do on the second line is find the `PAN` gesture associated with the `square` object and keep a reference to it.

Then, whenever we toggle by touching the circle we do the following:

```
gesture.enabled = !gesture.isEnabled;
```

That is, if the gesture is enabled then disable it (and vice-versa).

You can check out more on the [UIGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)